# Style Switcher Scriprs

Tags: javascript, jquery, styleswitching

I am very new to jQuery and Javascript so I'm having issues with my style switcher, the css part works but the script doesn't and I'm not sure how to do make it work.

**Javascript**:

```
$("#navorin li a").click(function() { 
    $("link.nav").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
    $("script.nav").attr("src",$(this).attr('role'));
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="navorin">
    <li><a href="#" rel="assets/css/leftmenu.css" role="assets/js/leftmenu.js">Left Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="assets/css/rightmenu.css" role="assets/js/rightmenu.js">Right Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="assets/css/topmenu.css" role="assets/js/topmenu.js">Top Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="assets/css/topmenufixed.css" role="assets/js/topmenufixed.js">Top Menu Fixed</a></li>
</ul>
```

**It changes these**:

```
<script class="nav" src="assets/js/leftmenu.js"></script>
<link class="nav" href="assets/css/leftmenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
```

**My menu scripts looks roughly like this, if that helps**:

```
    $(window).load(function () {
    $('.sidenav ul > li').click(function (ev) {
        $(this).find('>ul').fadeToggle();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.sidenav ul > li a.back').click(function (ev) {
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
});
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      $(document).on("swiperight", function () {
          $(".sidenav").addClass('sidenavhover');
          $(".overlay").fadeIn();
          $(".sidenav li.user").addClass('usershow');
      });
      $(document).on("swipeleft", function () {
          $(".sidenav").removeClass('sidenavhover');
          $(".sidenav ul > li ul").hide();
          $(".overlay").fadeOut();
          $(".sidenav li.user").removeClass('usershow');
      });
      $(".overlay").click(function () {
          $(".sidenav").removeClass('sidenavhover');
          $(".sidenav ul > li ul").hide();
          $(".overlay").fadeOut();
          $(".sidenav li.user").removeClass('usershow');
      });
  }
  if ($(window).width() >= 769) {
      $(".sidenav").mouseover(function () {
          $(".sidenav").addClass('sidenavhover');
          $(".sidenav li.user").addClass('usershow');
          $(".overlay").fadeIn();
      });
      $(".overlay").click(function () {
          $(".sidenav").removeClass('sidenavhover');
          $(".sidenav ul > li ul").slideUp(100);
          $(".sidenav li.user").removeClass('usershow');
          $(".overlay").fadeOut();
      });
  }  if ($(window).height() < 458) {
      $(".sidenav ul > li.logout").css('position', 'relative');
      $(".sidenav ul > li.logout").css('border-top', '0');
  }
  if ($(window).height() > 458) {
      $(".sidenav ul > li.logout").css('position', 'absolute');
      $(".sidenav ul > li.logout").css('border-top', '1px solid #eeeeee');
  }
  if ($(window).height() < 588) {
      $(".sidenav.sidenavhover ul > li.logout").css('position', 'relative');
      $(".sidenav.sidenavhover ul > li.logout").css('border-top', '0');
  }
  if ($(window).height() > 588) {
      $(".sidenav.sidenavhover ul > li.logout").css('position', 'absolute');
      $(".sidenav.sidenavhover ul > li.logout").css('border-top', '1px solid #eeeeee');
  }
});
```

If anyone could help my make it work that would be amazing

Thanks,
Alfred

Comment: Changing the src of a `<script>` doesn't "reload" the script as you would expect. You need to remove the script and add new one (google it).

Comment: ... and doing that won't undo the effects of the previous script; event handlers, global objects, etc will still exist. Basically this is just not the way to do things.

Comment: What's probably best is having a global variable for what style is currently being used, then execute functions from that in your script.

Comment: Another idea would be to create your style variants with a global class and simply add the class to the body on switching styles.

Comment: Is there any way of stoping a script executing? sorry but I'm not experienced

Comment: Metaphorically that's like fixing a car with duck-tape ...